# mysql link saved in database opening appended to original url

Tags: php, mysql, url

Difficult to explain this problem I'm having.  I have a textarea, user clicks to add a link and a window pops up to enter a link and link text...then that data gets appended to the textarea with the link tags.

```
<a target='_blank' href='www.something.com'>some website</a>
```

I'm saving the form data of the textarea as

```
$articleText = nl2br(htmlentities($_POST['articleText'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'));
```

When I get the data from the database I use

```
html_entity_decode($article, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
```

On the page the link looks as it should but when I click on it, new tab pop up but the url looks like this:

```
www.mywebsitename.com/'www.something.com/'
```

So obviously that doesn't work.  Anyone know what the problem is and how I can fix that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem here is we are not appending `http://` or `https://` before the link so it gets embedded with the old url. Therefore,
    `www.something.com` should be like `http://www.something.com` or `https://www.something.com`

Comment: It seems you are embedding extra single quotes here otherwise it should work as we are thinking for it.

Comment: Try it with **ENT_NOQUOTES** or **ENT_HTML5** `htmlentities($_POST['articleText'], ENT_HTML5, 'UTF-8')`

Comment: There were two problems.  One was the http or https...other was htmlentities was adding backslashes before quotes.  I used str_replace to get rid of them.  I think for the first problem I'll use javascript to check the entered links and append http is it's not there.  Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Links start with their protocol, such as "http://" or "https://" or just "//".

```
<a target='_blank' href='http://www.something.com'>some website</a>
```

Comment: I tried that too.  It will open the tab with the http appended to my url.  Still doesn't open the other website

Comment: If that is happening to you, then you are incorrect about what is being put out on your page.  You probably have an extra set of single quotes or encoded quotes, e.g. `'&apos;URL&apos;'`  Please add the entire output code in your question.